# CSS: forcing wrap word

Tags: css, symfony, word-wrap

I'm trying to create a `Symfony bundle` that reads a log file and convert it into more elegant page, but I have faced a problem with some text that is not wrapped into a div, although I have used `word-wrap : break-word;`:
My code:

```
<div class="card-stacked">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div style="word-wrap : break-word;">{{ log.description }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the resut I get:
[image]
How can I fix this please !

Comment: try with !important; 
css code
word-wrap:break-word !important;

Comment: This is usually a result of having a container with a fixed width, and not limiting the text with the same width property. I'd either say to make sure you got control of your width-CSS properties. That aside though, you can try adding !important to the word wrap and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @ShitalMarakana still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this  css code "word-wrap: break-word !important; word-break:break-all !important;"

```
<div class="card-stacked">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div style="word-wrap: break-word !important; word-break:break-all !important;">{{ log.description }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Happy to help you :)